# Error Loading Player. No playable sources found

Tags: android, android-webview, live-streaming

I am using WebView in my app. I have given the URL of page, web page loads correctly but streaming is not started and it says Error Loading Player. No playable sources found.

How to fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        try {
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("URL");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot load page",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you permit internet access in manifest?

Comment: yes..one link worked out of 4 5

Comment: http://life-optimized.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-play-html5-youtube-videos.html

Comment: http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/hls/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by launching a specific application for streaming the video.

BUT NOTE:

users with only 1 suitable video app, will not see the dialog.
Also, users that have set a default video app, will not see the dialog either.
Hence, I would not limit myself, by launching a specific video application, and instead let the android users have a nice android experience.

Should you have very good reasons to launch a specific video player, you can use:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad"); // Will launch MX player
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("your_path"), "video/*");
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    // the app mxplayer was not found...
    Toast.makeText(this, "mx player is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: installed it, but its not working. it still says mx player is not installed

Answer (score 0):

specify url like,

```
 webView.loadUrl(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497047/error-loading-player-no-playable-sources-found);
```

instead of,

```
 webView.loadUrl("URL");
```

Comment: i'm passing string url string in loadUrl